# Kendo MVC grid custom "contains" filter on array column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to understand how I would accomplish this:

```
Model:
 Id: int
 Name: string
 Languages : string[] - abbreviated and concat into a single string.  Column template shows "En|Fr" for instance.
```

**What I want to do** is provide a multi-select filter that allows me to check options "English", "French", "German", and/or "Spanish" for instance, and the DataSourceRequest would request that the  Languages collection "contains" whatever I check.

I have been unable to get the column configured correctly:

```
col.Bound(c => c.Languages)
    .ClientTemplate("#:formatLanguages(Languages)#") .Sortable(false)
      .Filterable(f=>f
      .Multi(true)
      ....what else?
);

function formatLanguages(langs) {
            result = [];
            langs.forEach((ele) => { result.push(ele.substring(0, 2)) });
            return result.sort().join('|');
}
```

1.) In Kendo.MVC how to a set a static datasource for the Filter options?

2.) How do I properly get the grid to pass a proper "contains" filter back via the DataSourceRequest?